# Como detecto el RESET de un formulario desde un elemento input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

tengo un formulario, y me preguntaba como puedo detectar el evento `reset` del formulario desde un input. Uso `React`, y tengo un componente `InputFile` dentro de un  y un componente Form.

Mi componente InputFile

```
function InputFile(props) {
    const text = props.text === undefined ? 'Archivo.pdf' : props.text
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState(text)
    function handleChange(e) {
        console.log('el form')
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
            setFileName(e.target.files[0].name)
        } else {
            setFileName(text)
        }
    }
    return (
        <label className={`label ${props.classes}`}>
            {props.label}
            <span className='file-input'>
                <span className='file-input__icon'><i className="fas fa-upload"></i></span>
                <span className='file-input__file-name'>
                    // CUANDO EL USUARIO RESETEA EL FORM, ME GUSTARIA CAMBIAR EL FILENAME
                    <span className='file-input__file-name-text'>{fileName}</span>
                </span>
                <input
                    name={props.name}
                    className='file-input__input'
                    type='file'
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    accept='.pdf' />
            </span>
        </label>
    )
}
```

Y mi componente Form sencillamente asi

```
<form>
         //Este componente detectaria el reset del form y modificaria su texto  
          personalizado
          <InputFile
                name='imagenContrato'
                label='Imagen Contrato'
                text='Foto.pdf' />

              <input type='reset' value='resetear'/>
              <input type='submit' value='enviar'/>
</form>
```

Comment: El evento `reset` corresponde al formulario o a un clic en el botón; de preferencia, escucha el evento en el formulario y ahí modificas el nombre.

Comment: Gracias, así lo hice, accedí al form Target desde el evento (e) y de ahí accedí a los nodos hijos que quería cambiar su texto, a través de querySelectorAll, no sé si es la mejor solución pero funciona perfectamente. Muchas gracias, estaba cabezón